# Bundle products: display something other than full product name in selector?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, bundled-product

This is easier to explain by example.

Let's say I sell T-shirts and other products. One shirt is available both alone and in a bundle with other products, and comes in several sizes. The shirt alone would be a configurable product, and when the customer views the product page they use a drop down with simple labels like "Size: Small" to select the size (and thus which simple product ends up in the cart).

With a bundle including the same shirt, the only way I can see to include it would be to have one of the bundle items have all of the simple products for the shirt. However, since it only seems to let you display the full product name, this means instead of a choice like "Size: Small" you get something like "Shirt: Example T-Shirt by Someguy Designs - Small". This makes for a messy and potentially confusing selection, especially with longer product names.

Is there a way to change the displayed text for a bundle option to something other than the full product name (ie "Small" instead of "Example T-Shirt by Someguy Designs - Small")? I know there are extensions that let you add configurable products to bundles and I imagine that might work in this particular example, but I'm looking for something a little more general if possible. There are other times where I would like to use something other than the full product name but don't have or want a configurable product to include instead.

I'd appreciate any help you could provide - thanks for your time!

Comment: This might be helpful- "Magento Bundle - Get attribute of option":
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11978585/magento-bundle-get-attribute-of-option

Answer (score 1):

I know exactly what you mean.  The easiest out of the box solution is to simply rename your products more efficiently.

Alternately to this, you can create a custom attribute like bundle_name, and give each simple a different name to use in the bundle.  You will then need to modify the code that grabs the attribute name and replace with bundle_name attribute value.

Comment: I understand exactly what you mean but don't know enough about Magento's internals to even know where to start looking for the bundle product display code to edit. Can you at least point me in the right direction? I should be able to handle the actual edits myself.